# Auto file updater in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety

In c# i m creating a application based on Thread, that read a text file from Computer(actually remote computer) selected by user. if user makes any changes in original file then this application should display the modified file(whole).

Successfully its doing but, thread that I am using don't know how and where to place that it continuous read the original file from background. My application gets hangs with this code

```
public partial class FormFileUpdate : Form
{
    // This delegate enables asynchronous calls for setting the text property on a richTextBox control.
    delegate void UpdateTextCallback(object text);

    // This thread is used to demonstrate both thread-safe and unsafe ways to call a Windows Forms control.
    private Thread autoReadThread = null;


    public FormFileUpdate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Creating Thread
        this.autoReadThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(UpdateText));
    }    

    private void openToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileOpen = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileOpen.Title = "Select a text document";
        fileOpen.Filter = @"Text File|*.txt|Word Document|*.rtf|MS office Documnet|*.doc|See All files|*.*";
        fileOpen.FilterIndex = 1;
        fileOpen.RestoreDirectory = true;
        fileOpen.Multiselect = false;
        if (fileOpen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {         
            //Created Thread will start here
            this.autoReadThread.Start(fileOpen.FileName);
        }
    }   

    private void UpdateText(object fileName)
    {    
        StreamReader readerStream = null;
        while(true)
        {
            if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                UpdateTextCallback back = new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText);
                this.Invoke(back, new object[] { fileName });
            }
            else
            {    
                try
                {
                    string fileToUpdate = (string)fileName;
                    readerStream = new StreamReader(fileToUpdate);
                    richTextBox1.Text = readerStream.ReadToEnd();
                }    
                catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }    
                finally
                {
                    if (readerStream != null)
                    {
                        readerStream.Close();
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional note to what Itay wrote:

You are calling `Thread.Sleep` from the GUI thread! Why do you even need to make a delay after closing the file? If you do need this delay for some reason (e.g. to avoid reading the file too frequently), don't put this delay on the GUI thread, because this will make your application unresponsive.

**EDIT: answering your question in the comment**

A possible cleaner way would be to set a `Timer` which would invoke a `BackgroundWorker` every x seconds.

The `BackgroundWorker` makes it very easy to run code in a background thread, and to have a callback run on the GUI thread when the work is completed. And you don't have to deal with `Invoke` and `InvokeRequired` directly.

Furthermore, I would create a class which wraps a `BackgroundWorker` to make it easy to pass data from the operation of reading the file (in the background thread), to updating the UI (in the GUI thread).

Answer (score 1):

1. You are making the file read from the GUI thread which is a time consuming action. Only the GUI update should be done with begin invoke.
2. Try not to use while(true), you can use the `FileSystemWatcher` class to update the display only when the file changes (Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7t1d0ky.aspx)).

Comment: so where should I create The Thread for file read? and if I use FileSystemWatch I don't think so I need to implement Threading

Comment: use `FileSystemWatcher`'s `Changed` event to watch for file changes and read the file when the event is being raised.